# Prove that if $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ then so is $|f|$?

Tags: calculus, proof-writing

Prove that if $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ then so is $|f|$.

I can prove the converse of this is false, I also try using the definition of integrable function $f$, but I don't know what to do after that

Comment: What is your definition of integrability? In any case if you managed to find a function $f$ with $|f|$ integrable but $f$ not integrable, you made a mistake.

Comment: No, she didn't. For instance, the function that's +1 on the rationals and -1 on the irrationals is not Riemann integrable on [0, 1]  (all upper sums are +1; all lower sums are -1, regardless of the partition chosen). But its absolute value, the function g(x) = 1, is most certainly integrable on the unit interval.

Comment: @John: That assumes the question is about Riemann integration.

Comment: Just a comment - boundedness of the interval is important. On $[1,\infty)$, $f(t) = (-1)^{\lfloor t\rfloor}\frac{1}{t}\chi_{[\lfloor t\rfloor, \lceil t\rceil]}$ is integrable but its absolute value most certainly is not.

Comment: @nik: The same example, slightly modified, works for Lesbegue integration: Let $C$ be a nonmeasurable subset of $[0, 1]$; then $f(x) = 2  \chi_C (x) - 1$ isn't integrable (using Royden's definition of Lesbegue integration, which only admits measurable functions; $\chi$ is the characteristic function of a set), but $|f|$, which is the constant function $1$, certainly *is* integrable.

Comment: I strongly suggest to specify what kind of integration are you talking about.

Comment: it's definite integral

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integrability means that certain sums involving value differences $|f(x)-f(x')|$ are small. Given that $\bigl||y|-|y'|\bigr|\leq|y-y'|$ the same sums with $|f|$ instead of $f$ tend to be even smaller.

Comment: To expand (see prob. 13-50 of Spivak's *Calculus*): $f$ is integrable IFF for any $\epsilon > 0$ there's a partition $P$ with $|L(f, P) - U(f, P)| < \epsilon$, where $L$ and $U$ are lower and upper sums.

For a partition $t_0, \ldots, t_k$, let $m_i = \inf_{x\in [t_i, t_{i+1}]} f(x)$, and let $M_i = \sup_{x\in [t_i, t_{i+1}]} f(x)$; let $m'_i$ and $M'_i$ be the corresponding things for $|f|$. Now show $M'_i = \max(|M_i|, |m_i|)$, $m'_i = \min(|M_i|, |m_i|)$ and then $M'_i - m'_i \le M_i - m_i$ (by cases). Then apply the "iff" statement above.

Answer (score 1):

One suggestion: Show that if $f$ and $g$ are integrable, then so is $\max(f, g)$. Then you can apply this lemma to $|f| = \max(f, -f)$.

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking about Riemann integration over a closed interval, it could help to know that *the composition of a continuous function with an integrable one is integrable*.

Comment: $x^{-1/2}$ is integrable on $[0,1]$ and the square function is continuous, right?

Comment: Can you clarify for us whether you're talking about Riemann integration or Lesbegue integration? (If this is a problem in a relatively early calculus course, and you're talking about upper and lower sums, but NOT about the measures of certain sets, then it's Riemann.)

Comment: @pppqqq : I think the result is that the composition of continuous with measurable (composed in the right order ) is measurable, not integrable.

Comment: Thank you guys, I simply assumed the post was talking about Riemann integral over a closed interval.

Comment: You could study Theorem 6.11 in *Principles of mathematical analysis* by Walter Rudin. It contains the desired statement for Riemann-Stieltjes integrals.

Comment: @John yes, I need to use the upper and lower sum to prove it