# Proof. sup{ f(x) } - inf{ f(x) } $\ge$ sup{ |f(x)| } - inf{ |f(x)| } (Abbott pp 198 q7.4.1)

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, intuition

Let f be a bounded function on a set A, and set 
$S = \sup\{f(x) : x ∈ A\}, I = \inf \{f(x) : x ∈ A\},$ 
$S' = \sup\{|f(x)| : x ∈ A\}, I' = \inf \{|f(x)| : x ∈ A\}.$   Show that $S - I ≥ S' - I'$.

> **1.** Intuition please? I believed because $-|r| \le r \le |r|$ for all real numbers $r$, ergo $\sup f(x) \le \sup \quad \color{seagreen}{|f(x)| \ge 0} \quad \implies S < S'$ and $\inf f(x) \ge \inf \quad \color{seagreen}{|f(x)| \ge 0} \quad \implies I > I'$.
>   But question is opposite! What did I flub?

Let e > 0 be arbitrary and choose $x_1$ and $x_2$ so that
$S' − e/2 < |f(x_1)|$ and $I' + e/2 > |f(x_2)|$.

> **2.** Where did these two inequalities issue from? How can we presage them?
>   **3.** Modus operandi of the proof please? This feels fey and occult.

Then using Exercise 1.2.5 (Reverse Triangle Inequality), 
[image]

> **4.** I don't understand the last red inequality. How does it engender $\le S - I$?

This question is ahead of [Prove that if $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ then so is $|f|$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/573257).

Answer (score 1):

Note that $I \le f(x) \le S$, and $-S \le -f(y) \le -I$, hence
$I-S \le f(x) -f(y) \le S-I$, in particular,
$|f(x)-f(y) | \le S-I$, since $S \ge I$.

The triangle equality gives
$|f(x)| -|f(y)| \le |f(x)-f(y) | \le S-I$ for all $x,y \in A$.

Taking the $\sup_x$ gives $S'-|f(y)| \le S-I$ for all $y \in A$.

Then take the $\sup_y$ gives 
$S'+\sup_y(-|f(y)|) \le S-I$, and since $\sup (-A) = - \inf A$ we have
$S'-\inf_y|f(y)| = S'-I' \le S-I$.